# How can i create shortcut

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I've HTC DESIRE 326g dual SIM with kit Kat working fine. I want to place a shortcut or any file actually on home screen . How to do that . Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install "ES file Explorer" from play store.

After installing come to home screen and long touch anywhere for about 3 secs.Now it should show an option to add widgets. Click on it. From the widgets list find ES file explorer app icon and drag it right into the home screen where you need to place the shortcut.

As soon as you place it a pop up window appears to select a file for which the shortcut needs to be created. Choose the file you wanted. That's it a shortcut for that file is created on the home screen.

Comment: Will Astro file manager do?

Comment: Mods please delete my first two comments.

Comment: Same way it worked with Astro file manager